# How Do I solve The Below System Of Equations By Using Substitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$a^2+b^2-c^2=0$$
$$5a-b=c$$
$$a+b+c=30$$

I have tried everything I could think of and I still don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: If $a+b+c=30$ and $c=5a-b$ then we'll have that $a+b+(5a-b)=30 \implies$...

Comment: $a=5;b=12;c=13$ is the root.

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2+b^2-c^2=0\tag 1$$
$$5a-b=c\tag 2$$
$$a+b+c=30\tag 3$$

Using $(2)$, $b=5a-c$. Plug in $(3)$ to get $6a=30$ that is to say $a=5$ and $b=25-c$. Plug in $(1)$ to get $650-50 c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First solve for $c$ in the first equation:
$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2 \\
c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

Now set the above equation equal to the second equation and get rid of the square root:
$$
5a-b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\
(5a-b)^2=a^2+b^2
$$

Now expand the left side and simplify:
$$
25a^2-10ab+b^2=a^2+b^2 \\
24a^2-10ab=0 \\
24a^2=10ab \\
24a=10b \\
2.4a=b
$$

Now plug your answer into the second equation:
$$
5a-2.4a=c \\
2.6a=c
$$

Now you can plug your values into the final equation:
$$
a+2.4a+2.6a=30 \\
a+5a=30 \\
6a=30 \\
a=5
$$

And finally, you can work backwards to find $b$ and $c$, which I will leave as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score 0):

From $a+b+c=30\Leftrightarrow c=30-a-b$ so we have a new system equation with $a;b$.

\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
        a^2+b^2 &= (5a-b)^2 (1) \\
        a^2+b^2 &= (30-a-b)^2 
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

Or $(5a-b)^2=(30-a-b)^2$

$\Leftrightarrow (a-5)(2a-b+15)=0$

**Case 1:** $a=5$. The equation $(1)\Leftrightarrow 5^2+b^2=(5\cdot 5-b)^2$

$\Leftrightarrow50b=600\Leftrightarrow b=12$. And $c=30-5-12=13$

**Case 2:** $b=2a+15$

The equation $(1)$ is equivalent to $a^2+(2a+15)^2=(5a-(2a+15))^2$

$\Leftrightarrow -4a^2+150a=0$.

If $a=0\Rightarrow b=15$ then $c=30-15-0=15$  but $5\cdot 0-15\ne 15$

If $a=\frac{75}{2}\Rightarrow b=90$ then $c=30-90-\frac{75}{2}=-\frac{195}{2}$ but $5\cdot \frac{75}{2}-90\ne -\frac{195}{2}$, too .

$\Rightarrow a=5;b=12;c=13$ is the root of system equation